# combine result into one table row that is exploded

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
<?php

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $combi = explode(",", $rows['keyword_id']);
    foreach($combi as $keyword_ids) {
        $sql = "SELECT keyword from keyword where keyword_id = '$keyword_ids'";
        $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: " + mysqli_error($con));
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $keyword_name = $row['keyword'];

            // $data[] = $row['keyword'];
            // $keyword_name = implode(', ', $data);

        }
    }

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="telco_name">' . $rows['name'] . '<input type="hidden" class="cross_sell_id" value=' . $rows['id'] . '> <input type="hidden" class="telco_id" value=' . $rows['tid'] . ' > </td>';
    echo '<td class="keyword_name">' . $keyword_name . ' <input type="hidden" class="keyword_id" value=' . $rows['keyword_id'] . ' > </td>';
    echo '<td class="main_cross" style="width:100px;">' . $rows['main_message'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="alternate_cross">' . $rows['alternate_message'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="start_date">' . $rows['start_timestamp'] . ' </td>';
    echo '<td class="end_date">' . $rows['end_timestamp'] . ' </td>';
```

What i want to be on my output is like this

```
<tr>
    <td> keyword_name, keyword_name </td>
    <td> keyword_name </td>
<tr>
```

How will i do that?

The data that is saved from the db. keyword_id is comma separated.

Comment: Do you want the tr to be loop?Or just one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the ids in a comma separated string, you can use an **IN** to get all the keywords in one query.

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $sql = "SELECT keyword_id,keyword from keyword where keyword_id IN ({$rows['keyword_id']})";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: " + mysqli_error($con));
    $keywords = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $keywords[$row['keyword_id']] = $row['keyword'];
    }
}

/* This line should display the keywords and set the value to the ids
 * however, it lacks both an id (for client side use) and a name (to 
 * send to the server)
 */
echo '<td class="keyword_name">' . implode(', ',$keywords) . ' <input type="hidden" class="keyword_id" value=' . implode(',',array_keys($keywords)) . ' > </td>';
```

Comment: hi sir. can i ask something regarding your answer?

Comment: I would be happy to answer a question

Comment: i now have like 3000+ datas on my database and the query starts to slowdown. is there something i can do to make the query fast again? based on your answer. thank you

Comment: Do you have an index on keyword_id?

Comment: You might want to open a new question and post the schema of the keyword table and the table that is referencing it, with the code.